# Janusgraph docker connect to cassandra docker and elasticsearch docker by docker net, and expose 8182 to host machine?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, cassandra, janusgraph

I am working with janusgraph. I have built a janusgraph image. What I want is to run this janusgraph container, at the same time, connect to cassandra container and elasticsearch container, and finally expose 8182 port to host machine.

My problem is: how to let janusgraph connect to cassandra by ip and 9042 port and elasticsearch by ip and 9200/9300 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to `EXPOSE` those ports in your Dockerfile.  Your Dockerfile is where you'll also want to define an `ARG` for the Cassandra cluster endpoints.

Dockerfile:

```
# argument for the Cassandra endpoints, with a default value of 127.0.0.1
ARG CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_LIST=127.0.0.1

# Exposing required ports 8182(gremlin) 9042(Cassandra) 9200(ElasticSearch)
EXPOSE 8182 9042 9200
```

Then do a regex/replace with `sed` in your entrypoint file:

```
sed -i "s/hostname=127\.0\.0\.1/hostname=${CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_LIST}/g" ${JANUSGRAPH_CONF}/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cql-es-server.properties
```

When building the Docker container, pass `CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_LIST` as a build argument:

```
--build-arg CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_LIST=1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5
```

This example is geared toward Cassandra, but something similar will work for ElasticSearch, too.

Note: You *could* also build all 3 inside the same container, and then you wouldn't need to pass the endpoints via `--build-arg`.  Although, you'd need enough RAM to support JVMs for Janus, Elastic, and Cassandra.